# Submarine crew fakes a software/virus-initiated missile attack to trick bad guy programmer into revealing the abort code

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I'm having trouble recalling which television show had an episode with a particular plot.  It was probably on TV in the **1990s** but could well have been a movie.  Haven't had much luck googling and searching/reading episode summaries on IMDB.

Plot points I recall (vaguely; may be inaccurate but they stick in my mind):

- On a **submarine**, there is a laptop with software (perhaps referred to as a "virus") that threatens to kill a bunch of innocent people, possibly by **launching nuclear missiles**.  At least, I'm fairly sure there was a submarine...
- Bad guy invents a software program to "**translate English into Japanese automatically**" (or possibly vice-versa).

  - I recall this seeming far-fetched at the time (using Google Translate recently triggered this memory).
  - It may have been late in the episode that the bad guy reveals his motivation; I think I mainly remember the ending.
- Bad guy becomes disgruntled after his employer **pays him just a salary while they make millions**.
- **The crew of the submarine fakes a malfunction in the software causing it to target the submarine**.

  - The bad guy falls for this trick and tells one of the good guys (possibly the female lead) how to disable the software (some **obscure keyboard shortcut** like "control+alt+shift+F9").

I have done some detailed searching of these series (but haven't watched them... yet ;-):

- *SeaQuest DSV* - I thought it was this show but so far haven't found an episode with the stated plot.  Even searched through online transcripts for all three seasons...
- *JAG* - I thought perhaps the submarine thing was making me think of SeaQuest and figured it might have been JAG.  There seem to be a lot of seasons and episodes but I only watched a handful.
- *Seven Days* - I read through the episode summaries and checked a few plausible ones found on YouTube but nothing convincing.

Comment: Well, you've definitely done your homework, maybe even one of the very few ID questions that might be worth an upvote. In fact I had to somehow think about *Seven Days*, too, when reading this, but more by feeling and atmosphere than by actual plot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are correct and that this is one of the early JAG episodes. I have very similar recollections.

Here's a description of [Episode 3 - Shadow](http://jag.djmed.net/5/shadow-3/), that I think fits the bill.

Comment: Incredible, that is it!  Thank you.  :-)  It also has the corny "cigar on top of the submarine" ending which I remember cringing at so long ago...

Comment: I should mention that I recall visiting that site and searching for keywords like "submarine", "translation" and "Japanese" without any luck.  Torpedo might have been the kicker, rather than "missile".